# How to make textfield accept decimal inputs in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have a calculator app in which I have a textfield in which if I enter any number; then it works fine. If I do not enter a number then it shows alert. I also want the user to be able to enter 1.5 but when I do this it shows alert "enter a number please"

So how can I enter decimal number? I am using the following code :

```
   NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];


  NSString*string=costToClientTextField.text;

 if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {


 UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Only a number can be entered into this input field " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];


 costToClientTextField.text=@"";


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "." in your set, like so

```
  NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber* candidateNumber;

    NSString* candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    range = NSMakeRange(0, [candidateString length]);

    [numberFormatter getObjectValue:&candidateNumber forString:candidateString range:&range error:nil];

    if (([candidateString length] > 0) && (candidateNumber == nil || range.length < [candidateString length])) {

        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help you. also put keyboard type number and punctuation.